# How do I safety check that there is no light in Darkroom / Darkbag?

Tags: film, developing, darkroom

Noon question, but:
How do I safety check that there is no light in Darkroom / Darkbag?

Comment: "Noon question" - I am not trying to nitpick on the typo, but it's funny. Keeping no light in darkroom at *noon* is probably even harder.
(sorry, I couldn't resist)

Comment: I was thinking to edit it, but in a way makes sense :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are talking about **locating a light leak in a changing bag** for loading film into magazines and cameras without a darkroom available…

Periodically, to check the condition of your changing bag, put a bright light inside the bag through one of the sleeves. Close up the bag. Sit in the darkroom or a closet with no light for a few minutes to let your eyes acclimate. Turn the bag over. Manipulate it. Turn it every which way. Look at it from all angles and pretty soon, you'll see every pinhole if there is one.

It's easier to see a bright light in a dark room because your eyes will dilate within a few minutes to rival a sensitive emulsion.

Good Luck.

Comment: Changing bag hack: Make a frame to keep the bag open like a tent frame using a construction set made of dowels and blocks such as TinkerToy™

Answer (score 32):

In the darkroom, place a piece of the material you will be developing, flat, face up, on the work space. Place a handful of coins on this material. Using a timer, remove a coin every 5 minutes. 12 coins will cover 1 hour. At the end of the time span, develop the film or photo paper. A perfect darkroom will leave no evidence. An unsafe darkroom, reveals circular images of the coins. This test will tell you how long it safe to have work out.

Comment: This is more useful with photo paper than film.

Comment: @Davidw Or sheet film, or (to a degree) medium format film. But not much useful for 35mm or small formats.

Comment: @Davidw -- Works for sheet film or 35mm or 16mm -- you just change the size to smaller objects.

Comment: @gparyani 35mm needs only to be pulled from the closed cassette by a fixed amount after each time interval, process, and then count the stripes after drying the roll.

Comment: @AlanMarcus Does one sit in the darkroom for 13 hours or can I get in and out somehow (or is this another question, kind of?) : ^ )

Comment: @Stan -- For this test -- one is after how long photo materials can be left out on the work surface and not be fogged by ambient or safelight. I think 1 hour is more than adequate.

Comment: @AlanMarcus I was being facetious. Yes, an hour would be sufficient. Thanx for the practicality. No doubt, some might actually have enough passion (and infinite patience) to actually do it.

Comment: @Stan: Some darkrooms have a sort of "air-lock" arrangement, with a short black hallway with doors on either end, and signs on the light side warning people to knock before opening the door.

Comment: @supercat I find your comment baffling! Do they have to hold their breath to get through the air lock?

Comment: @Stan: I was referring to the notion of an area with two doors which are never to be opened simultaneously.

Comment: @supercat I was being facetious. Yes, double doors are one good way to keep the dark from leaking out of a room. For the minimum amount of space, there are revolving doors, too. I also mentioned baffling which is how a light trap (or maze) door works. I was in a silly mood. Thank you for being kind.